# array_push with multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to store days of recurrence and trying to make a check for if there are more than one day the client has an appointment. I am just trying to push into a basic multi-dimensional array with an i variable keeping track of the 1st index key, but get a

I've tried putting them into strings and just concatenating the strings in cases of multiple frequencies but that doesn't help me when I am doing my later check to go to the next occurrence of that appointment using date modify.

```php
$days = array(array());
        $i=0;
        foreach($recurring_appt as $rec){
            $check = str_split($rec->frequency_data);
            if($check[0] == 'x'){
               array_push($days[$i], 'sunday');}
            if($check[1] == 'x'){
                array_push($days[$i],'monday');}
            if($check[2] == 'x'){
                array_push($days[$i],'tuesday');}
            if($check[3] == 'x'){
                array_push($days[$i], 'wednesday');}
            if($check[4] == 'x'){
               array_push($days[$i], 'thursday');}
            if($check[5] == 'x'){
                array_push($days[$i],'friday');}
            if($check[6] == 'x'){
                array_push($days[$i], 'saturday');}
            $i++;
        }
```

This results in this error: "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that exception because you're trying to push to a non existing array index which should also be an array. You can avoid that exception by verifying if the array exists and initializing it, after the foreach instruction.

```
$days = array(array());
$i=0;
foreach($recurring_appt as $rec){
    if (!isset($days[$i])) {
        $days[$i] = array();
    }

    $check = str_split($rec->frequency_data);

    if($check[0] == 'x'){
       array_push($days[$i], 'sunday');
    }

    if($check[1] == 'x'){
        array_push($days[$i],'monday');
    }

    if($check[2] == 'x'){
        array_push($days[$i],'tuesday');
    }

    if($check[3] == 'x'){
        array_push($days[$i], 'wednesday');
    }

    if($check[4] == 'x'){
       array_push($days[$i], 'thursday');
    }

    if($check[5] == 'x'){
        array_push($days[$i],'friday');
    }

    if($check[6] == 'x'){
        array_push($days[$i], 'saturday');
    }

    $i++;
}
```

On PHP7+ you can push element withou `array_push` like this:

```
$days[$i][] = 'sunday';
```